# Looking for Fortran code calculating drainage basin area

Tags: dem, modelling, hydrology

I am working in a project of glacier mass balance.
For my project I want to integrate the area of the drainage basin in a glaciological system model (GSM). As the drainage area changes with time due to topographic evolution (ice accumulation or melt), I need to be able to integrate some code which calculates this area in the GSM. Would anybody know where I could find some code to compute the drainage area of a region?

Comment: The 80's called. They want their programming language back. :p May I ask why you are asking for Fortran code?

Comment: I think the OP needs FORTRAN because the GSM is written in FORTRAN. FORTRAN is still very popular in large computational models, e.g. climate models.

Comment: the GSM is effectivly written in fortran but if you know about a model in another language I could convert it.

Comment: Is there any chance of calling an external program (eg, arcmap with Python) to do it for you, and dump the output somewhere usable? I'm not familiar with fortran's abilities, so that's why I ask. I'd recommend that as a simpler route. If not, you might check with the people who wrote ArcHydro at University of Texas: http://www.crwr.utexas.edu/giswr/hydro/ - I don't know if they use ArcGIS' builtin drainage area calculations or not, but I think otherwise they probably have some .NET code for it.

Comment: Check [HEC-RAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEC-RAS).

Answer (score 3):

Sue Greenlee's original code - that Esri's and many other watershed codes are based on - was published in FORTRAN in 1988. I'd go looking for that - don't see it on the web - but you could always email her! Kind of surprised it's not in GitHub, it's pretty neat code.

Jenson S. K. and J. O. Domingue. 1988. Extracting Topographic Structure from Digital Elevation Data for Geographic Information System Analysis. Photogrammetric Engineering and Remote Sensing 54 (11): 1593-1600.